# Active Directory logs in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory

I cannot seem to get my Active Directory log files into AWS CloudWatch. I'm getting all my Windows Event logs, but not these.

I've tried multiple paths with wildcards and without. The path is C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs.

Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.